# Pandas check if cell value is between range from another data frame

Tags: python, pandas

So I have two data frames. Df1 has names and values as follows:

| Source | Target | volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dog | cat | 3 |
| cat | rat | 2 |

Df2 has range for each name as follows:

| name | min | max |
| --- | --- | --- |
| dog | 1 | 2 |
| cat | 1 | 3 |

what I would like to achieve is to check if the values in source or target columns in df1 exist in name column in df2, and if they exist to check if the volume is between them min and max values and result a data frame as shown below:

| Source | Target | volume | S. in range | S. min | S. max | T. in range | T. min | T.max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| dog | cat | 3 | No | 1 | 2 | Yes | 1 | 2 |
| cat | rat | 2 | yes | 1 | 3 | - | - | - |

If the name does no exist in df2 there should be a line or similar indicating that the name was not found.

Im not entirely sure how to get this work as I need to check for values from two columns and combine them into one data frame.

Comment: Should the column `values` in `Df1` be `volume` instead ?

Comment: @SeaBean - I think yes, so edited question.

Comment: @jezrael  Excellent!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.set_index()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) on `df2` to make it a lookup table by `name`.  Then use [`.map()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to map the `Source` and `Target` to get the `min`, `max` values:

```
df2a = df2.set_index('name')
df3 = df1.copy()

df3['S.in range'] = np.where(df3['Source'].isin(df2['name']), df3['volume'].between(df3['Source'].map(df2a['min']), df3['Source'].map(df2a['max'])), None)
df3['S.min'] = df3['Source'].map(df2a['min'])
df3['S.max'] = df3['Source'].map(df2a['max'])
df3['T.in range'] = np.where(df3['Target'].isin(df2['name']), df3['volume'].between(df3['Target'].map(df2a['min']), df3['Target'].map(df2a['max'])), None)
df3['T.min'] = df3['Target'].map(df2a['min'])
df3['T.max'] = df3['Target'].map(df2a['max'])

df3['S.in range'] = df3['S.in range'].replace({False: 'No', True: 'Yes'})
df3['T.in range'] = df3['T.in range'].replace({False: 'No', True: 'Yes'})
```

**Result:**

```
print(df3)


  Source Target  volume S.in range  S.min  S.max T.in range  T.min  T.max
0    dog    cat       3         No      1      2        Yes    1.0    3.0
1    cat    rat       2        Yes      1      3       None    NaN    NaN
```

(I suppose the column `values` should be named `volume` according to description and expected result.  If not the case, can use `values` in the codes above and rename it if necessary for desired output).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join and rename columns for new `DataFrame`s, then join in [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and set `in range` columns by [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) for also test if no match, so assigned `None`s and [`Series.between`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html):

```
df3 = (df1[['Source','volume']].rename(columns={'Source':'in range'})
        .merge(df2.rename(columns={'name':'in range'}), on='in range', how='left'))
df4 = (df1[['Target','volume']].rename(columns={'Target':'in range'})
         .merge(df2.rename(columns={'name':'in range'}), on='in range', how='left'))

df = pd.concat([df1, 
                df3.drop('volume',axis=1).add_prefix('S.'),
                df4.drop('volume',axis=1).add_prefix('T.')], axis=1)

m10 = df['S.min'].isna()
m11 = df['volume'].between(df['S.min'], df['S.max'])

m20 = df['T.min'].isna()
m21 = df['volume'].between(df['T.min'], df['T.max'])

df['S.in range'] = np.select([m10, m11], [None, 'Yes'], 'No')
df['T.in range'] = np.select([m20, m21], [None, 'Yes'], 'No')
print (df)
  Source Target  volume S.in range  S.min  S.max T.in range  T.min  T.max
0    dog    cat       3         No      1      2        Yes    1.0    3.0
1    cat    rat       2        Yes      1      3       None    NaN    NaN
```